# 2018: a year in moderation

Tags: discussion, moderation, statistics

It's New Year's Day in [Stack Exchange land](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zulu_Time)...

A distinguishing characteristic of these sites is how they are moderated:

> We designed the Stack Exchange network engine to be mostly self-regulating, in that we amortize the overall moderation cost of the system across thousands of teeny-tiny slices of effort contributed by regular, everyday users.
> -- [A Theory of Moderation](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/)

While there certainly are [Moderators](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/11/21/our-theory-of-moderation-re-visited/) here, a significant amount of the *moderation* is done by ordinary people, using the privileges
they've earned by virtue of their contributions to the site. Each of you contributes a little bit of time and effort, and together you accomplish much.

As we enter a new year, let's pause and reflect, taking a moment to appreciate the work that we do here together.
To that end, here is how the moderation done here on Open Data breaks down by activity over the past 12 months:

```
                 Action                  Moderators Community¹
---------------------------------------- ---------- ----------
Users suspended²                                  0          4
Tasks reviewed³: Suggested Edit queue            14        254
Tasks reviewed³: Reopen Vote queue                0          7
Tasks reviewed³: Low Quality Posts queue         11         94
Tasks reviewed³: Late Answer queue                0        119
Tasks reviewed³: First Post queue                 0        647
Tasks reviewed³: Close Votes queue                0         78
Tags merged                                       9          0
Tag synonyms proposed                            10          0
Tag synonyms created                              9          0
Questions reopened                                2          0
Questions protected                               1          3
Questions migrated                                4          0
Questions flagged⁴                                3         46
Questions closed                                 49          0
Question flags handled⁴                          26         23
Posts unlocked                                    0          1
Posts undeleted                                   7          4
Posts locked                                      0         25
Posts deleted⁵                                   46        200
Posts bumped                                      0        465
Comments undeleted                                3          0
Comments flagged                                  2        137
Comments deleted⁶                                60        156
Comment flags handled                            82         57
Answers flagged                                  13        156
Answer flags handled                            129         40
```

#### Footnotes

¹ "Community" here refers both to [the membership of Open Data](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/users) *without* [diamonds next to their names](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators), and to the automated systems otherwise known as [user #-1](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/users/-1).

² The system will suspend users under three circumstances: when a user is recreated after being previously suspended, when a user is recreated after being destroyed for spam or abuse, and when a network-wide suspension is in effect on an account.

³ This counts every review that was submitted (not skipped) - so the 3 suggested edits reviews needed to approve an edit would count as 3, the goal being to indicate the frequency of moderation actions. This also applies to flags, etc.

⁴ Includes close flags (but *not* close or reopen votes).

⁵ This ignores numerous deletions that happen automatically in response to some other action.

⁶ This includes comments deleted by their own authors (which also account for some number of handled comment flags).

Wishing you all a happy new year...

Comment: what prompted you to do this? very interesting, appreciate the effort.

Comment: Seems to come in handy now and again; I've posted these here & there in the past, but usually not often enough.

Comment: maybe its cause you're a community mod